# How to update data at a particular line in a file?

Tags: c++, file, iostream, file-handling

Consider i have following file ("testt.txt")

```
abc
123
def
456
ghi
789
jkl
114
```

Now if i wanted to update the figure next to name `ghi` (i.e. `789`),
how would i do it?

The following code helps me reach there quickly no doubt, but how to update it quickly?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int counter = 0;
    string my_string;
    int change = 000;
    ifstream file ( "testt.txt" );

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        getline(file, my_string, '\n');
        if (my_string == "ghi") 
        {
            ofstream ofile ( "testt.txt" );
            for (int i = 0; i < counter + 1; i++)
            {
                //reached line required i.e. 789
                //how to process here?
            }
            ofile.close();
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << counter << endl;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly the counter here is 5 corresponding to "ghi",
so counter + 1 would point to value `789`. How to change it to `000`?

------------SOLVED-----------FINAL CODE------

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<string>
 #include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
string x;
ifstream file ( "testt.txt" );
ofstream ofile ( "test2.txt" );
while (!file.eof())
{
    getline(file,x);
    if (x == "789")
    {
        ofile << "000" << endl;
    }
    else
        ofile << x << endl;
}
file.close();
ofile.close();
remove("testt.txt");
return 0;
}
```

Output ("test2.txt")

```
abc
123
def
456
ghi
000
jkl
114
```

Comment: [`while(!file.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Consider using a database, because those operations tend to be complicated using simple file access. Anyhow, the way you approach the problem, it boils down to "read data", "modify data", "write data", which is cumbersome but possible. At which step exactly do you have problems?

Comment: you can see, it is written in for loop,, and any other method that can be used without database?? i mean to write updated data to a new file and delete old one..

Comment: @bikrathor It is possible if you have all certain fixed positions of data. Look into the [`std::basic_ostream::seekp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) method.

Answer (score 2):

If you open a file with `ifstream` for reading, and then with `ofstream` for writing, the `ofstream` will either not work or overwrite the file - I am not sure which option is right, but neither is what you want.

So use `std::fstream` to open a file for reading and writing:

```
fstream file ( "testt.txt" );
```

After arriving to the proper place, use the `seekp` method to enable writing to the stream after reading from it (it often works without `seekp`, but when it fails, the bug is very difficult to find), as required by the Standard:

```
if (my_string == "ghi") 
{
    file.seekp(file.tellg());
    ...
    break;
}
```

When modifying files, you have to replace the existing bytes with the new ones. It's important to write exactly 3 bytes, so the value `789` is overwritten properly. So you may want to check the range:

```
if (change < 0 || change > 999)
    abort(); // or recover from the error gracefully
```

And set the width of the output field before writing it:

```
file << setw(3) << change;
```

If your code switches from writing back to reading, use `file.seekg(file.tellp())` to ensure it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that is not generally easy, because file systems don't store files line-wise, but instead as sequence of bytes. So if you replace a line with let's say 4 characters in it by a line with 5 characters, you will overwrite something in your next line. You'd have to read the file into memory, and then re-write everything from your changed line on.

That's a horrible approach, because it is incredibly slow, and if you can avoid it by not using a text file to store this kind of information, you should do that. I generally recommend using something like `sqlite`, for which libraries for all relevant languages exist, if you need to store data in things that feel like tables; for other kind of data, there's other approaches than relational databases, but that depends on what you want to actually store.

Comment: _"There's no way to do that ..."_ That's simply not true.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yeah, and I even go as far as describing how it's possible... Well, I'm off, editing my answer.

Comment: Not really, in terms of answering the OP's original question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That depends on what you view as the "original question", and even more on whether you view "original question" as a relevant concept -- you know, everything flows :-D no, in fact, OP asked how to change that line, and my answer was "write the new line and all lines following", and I honestly believe that answers his question. The "no way to do that" start of my answer came from OP asking "is there a way to do that quickly", and generally, there's not, if his file goes on for Gigabytes.

Comment: Take OP's seriously in what they want to achieve in code, and show them how to. If you think it's an XY problem asked for, then extend this as a comment or additional notes in your answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Definitely taking OP seriously. The question was *The following code help me reach there quickly no doubt, but how to update it quickly??*, and my answer is *how you can update it and why it's not generally possible to do it fast*, so I think it doesn't need further commentation; I see you disagree with me here.

Comment: @marcus , could you please help me onto how to start editing from that line and write onto a new file??

Comment: @bikrathor: Use your existing code to write every line you read (up to, and including "ghi") to your `ofile`, then write `"000"`,and skip the next line on the input file, and then continue to write everything that is in the input file to the output file.

Comment: o yeah great @marcus, and any way there to delete the old one i.e testt.txt??

Comment: @bikrathor: try not using the same in and output file, for that matter; you'll notice that the "old" line never gets written to the output file. As I explained in my answer, you will have to read in everything that comes after "ghi" into memory, and then put it back into your combined in- and output file if you need to change the length of your line.

Comment: yeah i wrote the following code, and it created a new file my work done but how to delete the old one i.e. testt.txt?

Comment: string x;
 ifstream file ( "testt.txt" );
 ofstream ofile ( "test2.txt" );
 while (!file.eof())
 {
  getline(file,x);
  if (x == "456")
  {
   ofile << "000" << endl;
  }
  else
   ofile << x << endl;
    }
 file.close();
 ofile.close();

Comment: yeah it does but now i want to but now i want to delete the old one dude

Comment: @bikrathor: Ah you mean "delete the file", and not "delete the line", here. Well: `#include <cstdio>` and then `std::remove("filename")`, see `man remove` or http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/

Comment: @bikrathor: happy to hear it worked out. I think my answer would profit from you editing it, adding your (complete) code, so that people can later find it :)